# Socket not connecting with IPEndPoint

Tags: c#, networking

I have a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` connecting to a back end.

```
public class Connection
{
    private readonly Socket _client;
    private readonly IPEndPoint _endPoint;

    byte[] _sendBuf = new byte[0x1000];

    protected Connection(string host, int port)
    {
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(host);
        _endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        _client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    protected void Connect()
    {
        //Fails
        _client.Connect(_endPoint);
    }
}
```

The socket tries to connect but timeouts when `Connect` function is called. But if I provide `host` and `port` parameters to `Socket.Connect` function instead of an `IPEndPoint` with those, it connects successfully.

```
    protected void Connect()
    {
        //Connects
        _client.Connect(host, port);    //same as used in creating IPEndPoint above
    }
```

Why? The end point I'm trying to connect is in a VPN with the network I'm in.

Comment: can you provide the socket details?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee : Do you mean the end point details? It's an address in a VPN.

Comment: No What I meant was which Socket were you using like there are different sockets available in the market.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee : `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`

Comment: What is the host resolved to (which IP is returned from Parse)? And what is the host string before the resolution?

Comment: @jgauffin : The host resolved from `Parse` and before are the same